# How can I edit a widget value while posting?

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

Lets see the action (form is based on model)

```
$this->form->bind ($request->getParameter('task'));
if ($this->form->isValid())
{
    // cakk
}
```

This all works good, its not valid when its really not valid etc.

But I want to edit some fields, for example a date must be always set to now. Or a password must be encoded. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `doSave()` method in the form .. something like this :

```
public function doSave($con = null)
{
   $this->values['form field'] = 'newvalue';
   parent::doSave($con);
}
```

`$this->values` is an array containing the values on the form.

### Update

You could use a post validator .. like this (again in the form class) :

```
$this->validatorSchema->setPostValidator(
     new sfValidatorCallback(array('callback' => array($this, 'methodName')))
);

public function methodName($validator, $values)
{
    // check / change what you need to
    $values['fieldname'] = 'new value';
    // return values
    return $values;
}
```